# Request from Frontend Container to Backend container

Tags: docker, vuejs2, docker-compose

I have seen several possibilities how to communicate between docker containers. I tried the most of them except proxying which i cant translate to my scenario.

I have a vue-`frontend`, java-`backend`- container.
In the frontend i use `axios` to make http request.

I want to make a http request `axios.get(http:localhost:7080/ping)`, which gives me status 200 but I dont get an response and some CORS problem.(Which is very strange, because the cors header are present if i use postman for the request)

If i use `axios.get(http:container_name:7080/ping)` I get some other error
`net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`.

Other solutions (using nginx) using reverse proxy. Do I need something like this or do I have some other misconfiguration?

My `docker-compose` looks like this:

```
    services:
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build: ./backend
    volumes:
      - xxx
    ports:
      - 7048:7048
      - 7080:7080
      - 7009:9009
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build: 
      context: ../frontend
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    volumes: 
      - ../xxx
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      #- 8001:8001
    depends_on:
      - backend
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
     # - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

Comment: Where is the actual HTTP call happening?  Is the `frontend` container directly calling the backend, or is it serving up a Web application that's making the outbound HTTP call from the user's browser?

Comment: The frontend containers serves a vue.js application which makes the call to the backend

Comment: ...so the URL needs to be a name the _browser_ can resolve, which is probably the host name of the server running the `backend` container (could be `localhost` only in a development environment where you know the browser and the Docker setup are running on the same physical host).

Comment: which is contradictory to the already given answer?....